# Error while updating TestCase with Tag using Rally Java API

Tags: java, rally

I am trying to update a TestCase in Rally with an existing Tag, however I am getting an error from server.
My steps are:

1. Find the testcase based on the test ID, keep the ref and the Tags object
2. Find the tag, keep the reference
3. If the _tagsNameArray json array does not contain my tag, update it
4. Send the update to Rally server

Here's the code I have for updating the testcase:

```
String tagref = getTagReference(tagname); //this is where I get the reference to the existing Tag
QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "Tags"));
testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=",  testID));
QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse;
testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
JsonArray resultArray = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults();
if (resultArray.size() == 0) {
 System.out.println("Test " + testID + "does not exist anymore");
            return;
}
JsonObject testCaseJson = resultArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
String testCaseRef = testCaseJson.get("_ref").getAsString();
JsonObject tasks = testCaseJson.get("Tags").getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray taskarray = tasks.get("_tagsNameArray").getAsJsonArray();
boolean tagfound = false;
for (JsonElement el : taskarray) {
  JsonObject task = el.getAsJsonObject();
  String tgnm = task.get("Name").getAsString();
  if (tgnm.contentEquals(tagname)) {
   tagfound = true;
   break;
  }
}
if (!tagfound) {
  String shortref = Ref.getRelativeRef(tagref);
  String shorttestref = Ref.getRelativeRef(testCaseRef);
  JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
  json.addProperty("Name", tagname); // not mandatory, I guess
  json.addProperty("_ref", shortref);
  taskarray.add(json);
  tasks.add("_tagsNameArray", taskarray);
  JsonObject updateTCJson = new JsonObject();
  updateTCJson.add("Tags", tasks);
  UpdateRequest updateTestCaseRequest = new UpdateRequest(testCaseRef, updateTCJson);
  UpdateResponse updateTestCaseResponse = restApi.update(updateTestCaseRequest);
  if (updateTestCaseResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
   System.out.println("Updated Test Case with tag: " + tagname);
  } else {
  System.err.println("Cannot update test case tags pentru ca: "+updateTestCaseResponse.getErrors()[0]);
}
```

Problem is, I am getting this from server:

```
 {"OperationResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": ["Could not read: Could not read referenced object 2"], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."]}}
```

This is killing me, I spent a lot of time debugging, I cannot find the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check the difference between the taskarray and the existing task(s)? Maybe try commenting `tasks.add("_tagsNameArray", taskarray);` and report your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an app example that updates Tags collection on a TestCase. I noticed you are using `_tagsNameArray`.  `_tagsNameArray` collection is not defined in Rally schema and should not be relied upon for implementation. The source is in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/tree/master/updateTagsOnTestCase).

```
public class UpdateTestCaseWithTag {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


           String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
           String apiKey = "_abc123";
           String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1234567";
           String applicationName = "RestExample_updateTCwithTag";


           RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
           restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        try {
            String tagname = "tag1";
            String testid = "TC32";
            QueryRequest  tagRequest = new QueryRequest("Tag");
            tagRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
            tagRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", tagname));
            QueryResponse tagQueryResponse = restApi.query(tagRequest);
            if(tagQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount() == 0){
                System.out.println("Cannot find tag: " + tagname);
                return;
            }
            JsonObject tagJsonObject = tagQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String tagRef = tagJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
            System.out.println(tagRef);
            QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            testCaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
            testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "Tags"));
            testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=",  testid));
            QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);;

            if (testCaseQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount() == 0) {
             System.out.println("Cannot find test case : " + testid);
             return;
            }
            JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String testCaseRef = testCaseJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
            System.out.println(testCaseRef);
            int numberOfTags = testCaseJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Tags").get("Count").getAsInt();
            System.out.println(numberOfTags + " tag(s) on " + testid);
            QueryRequest tagCollectionRequest = new QueryRequest(testCaseJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Tags"));
            tagCollectionRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name"));
            JsonArray tags = restApi.query(tagCollectionRequest).getResults();

            for (int j=0;j<numberOfTags;j++){
                System.out.println("Tag Name: " + tags.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));
            }
            tags.add(tagJsonObject);
            JsonObject testCaseUpdate = new JsonObject();
            testCaseUpdate.add("Tags", tags);
            UpdateRequest updateTestCaseRequest = new UpdateRequest(testCaseRef,testCaseUpdate);
            UpdateResponse updateTestCaseResponse = restApi.update(updateTestCaseRequest);
            if (updateTestCaseResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully updated : " + testid + " Tags after update: ");
                QueryRequest tagCollectionRequest2 = new QueryRequest(testCaseJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Tags"));
                tagCollectionRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name"));
                JsonArray tagsAfterUpdate = restApi.query(tagCollectionRequest).getResults();
                int numberOfTagsAfterUpdate = restApi.query(tagCollectionRequest).getResults().size();
                for (int j=0;j<numberOfTagsAfterUpdate;j++){
                    System.out.println("Tag Name: " + tagsAfterUpdate.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   

    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks! I was messing directly with the object received, without doing a new Query on the Tags. Working fine now!